# Помощь с функией с++

Tags: c++

Всем привет, у меня есть функции сортировки:
Появляються ерори:

1. Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
   Error   C3867   'Class_for_admin::SortSetSs': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member    Kursova_Robota  C:\Users\Thinkpad T560\source\repos\Kursova_Robota\Kursova_Robota\Kursova.cpp   285
2. Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
   Error   C2672   'sort': no matching overloaded function found   Kursova_Robota  C:\Users\Thinkpad T560\source\repos\Kursova_Robota\Kursova_Robota\Kursova.cpp   285
3. Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
   Error   C2780   'void std::sort(const _RanIt,const _RanIt)': expects 2 arguments - 3 provided   Kursova_Robota  C:\Users\Thinkpad T560\source\repos\Kursova_Robota\Kursova_Robota\Kursova.cpp   285

Не знаю как пофиксить, может кто-то знает?
КОД:

```
bool SortSetSs(Class_for_admin FirstP, Class_for_admin SecondP)
    {
        return (strcmp(FirstP.SecName2, SecondP.SecName2) < 0);
    }

    bool SortSetBb(Class_for_admin FirstA, Class_for_admin SecondA)
    {
        return (strcmp(FirstA.ChildName2, SecondA.ChildName2) < 0);
    }

    bool SortSetAa(Class_for_admin FirstD, Class_for_admin SecondD)
    {
        return (FirstD.Plata2 > SecondD.Plata2);
    }

    void SortSs()
    {
        sort(Spysok2, Spysok2 + N, SortSetSs);
        Display();
    }

    void SortBb()
    {
        sort(Spysok2, Spysok2 + N, SortSetBb);
        Display();
    }

    void SortAa()
    {
        sort(Spysok2, Spysok2 + N, SortSetAa);
        Display();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращение к функциям сравнения исправить вот таким образом:

```
void SortSs()
{
    sort(Spysok2, Spysok2 + N, &SortSetSs);
    Display();
}
```

Comment: Еще ерор: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2276 '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression Kursova_Robota C:\Users\Thinkpad T560\source\repos\Kursova_Robota\Kursova_Robota\Kursova.cpp 297

Comment: Методы класса нужно сделать статическими

Comment: спасибо за помощь,пофиксил)